# Sharepoint online admin tasks that can be automated

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business, sharepoint-administration, sharepoint-admin-center, azure-automation

I will soon be getting on a project as sharepoint online admin "(including onedrive, yammer). I am compiling a list of tasks that I can automate to make my job easier.

Can you suggest some tasks that you automated which made your job faster? Any already developed scripts would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Some scripts and automation I regularly use as a Developer, Designer, Architect:

- Provisioning sites (Columns, Content Types, Lists, Views)
- Changing Permissions (Orphaned Users, Adding / Removing from groups, creating groups)
- Creating Folder Structures (Yes, legacy users still demand folders)
- Enabling Features (Publishing)
- Enable external sharing on site collections
- Delete Lists & Libraries
- Automating Farm Inventories
- Associate with Hub site
- Exporting / Importing Term sets

There is so much more you can do with automation, just be sure it's worth it and will save time when comparing to manual effort.